# Polymer issue for working file

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, custom-element

**Question 1:**
The below code works in polymer. I don't quite understand how. I didn't have to do something like `var el = new Element()` or I didn't have append it to the document explicitly.

**Question 2:** How can I eliminate the `<my-element></my-element>` tag?

MyElement.html

```
// After Importing all the necesarry files
var Element= Polymer({
    is: 'my-element'
    created: function (){
    this.textContent = "My Element"
    },
});
```

index.html
(After importing all necessary files)

```
<body>
  <my-element></my-element>
</body>
```

Comment: My youtube playlist to help to understand why you should not eliminate the tag, https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAgb4zAe1lZXlfqhAXJxY8A1LZtGV3v3X

Answer (score 0):

You can if you want,

```
// create an instance with createElement:
var el1 = document.createElement('my-element');

// ... or with the constructor:
var el2 = new MyElement();
```

Ref. https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#register-element

But, the beauty is the tag itself. More to read on custom elements,

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements
https://www.webcomponents.org/introduction#specifications

Answer (score 0):

1. If you use **Polymer({})** constructor, it set up custom element's prototype chain and register it immediately.  If you want setup and register whenever want use **Polymer.class({})** , them call **document.registerElement('my-element', MyElement);**
2. We cannot eliminate component tag, if we delete that tag LocalDom wont display